# RStudio - change variable based on something contained in another

Tags: r, regex, qdap

I'm using RStudio and have an utterance variable and a syllables variable with the syllable count. Every utterance that contains "t-shirt" needs one syllable count more. (Automatically qdap syllable_sum gave "t-shirt" it 1 (it needs 2)).

An example: yellow t-shirt has 3 (it needs 4 syllables).

I don't want to write everything that I have tried that hasn't worked.
I have found examples of this, but not for R that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

You need the magic of `grepl{}`

```
install.packages("grepl")
library(grepl)

mydf$syllables <- syllable_sum(mydf$label)
mydf$syllables <- ifelse(grepl("t-shirt", mydf$label), 
                               mydf$syllables+1, mydf$syllables)
mydf
```

Comment: Where is the function `syllable_sum` coming from? Are you trying to define it on the next line?

Comment: The function syllable_sum is from qdap. I should have included library(qdap) in my post. Sorry that wasn't clear enough.